# How to maintain syntax group precedence with region offsets in Vim

Tags: vim

I am confused by vim's syntax group precedence behavior. It seems that adding an offset to a region start/end match alters a group's precedence:

## Trial 1

#### syntax file

```
syn region t1 start='AAA' end='BBB'
syn region t2 start='AAA' end='BBB'
```

#### test text

```
AAA this is a test BBB  # in group t2, as expected by precedence
```

## Trial 2

#### syntax file

```
syn region t1 start='AAA' end='BBB'
syn region t2 start='AAA'ms=e+1 end='BBB'
```

#### test text

```
AAA this is a test BBB  # now in group t1-- why?
```

## Trial 3

#### syntax file

```
syn region t2 start='AAA'ms=e+1 end='BBB'
```

#### test text

```
AAA this is a test BBB  # matches t2, as expected
```

Both regions `t1` and `t2` match the text, regardless of whether an offset is added to the start/end patterns. By Vim's rules of syntax group precedence, `t2` should take precedence over `t1` in both Trial 1 and Trial 2 because it is defined later. But `t1` has precedence in Trial 2, where a start-match offset has been added. So it seems that adding an offset to the start/end pattern somehow moves a group to the back of the precedence hierarchy?

How can I make `t2` supersede t1 even when I add a start-match offset?

**NOTE**: This example is contrived-- my use case is trying to include a different syntax under certain keys in a YAML file, and there I am having trouble with the YAML syntax groups overriding my regions.